# MongoDB Aggregation - query collections that satisfies all array of objects not at least one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collections that have dates in an array like:

```
datesArray: [{
 start_date: Date,
 end_date: Date
}]
```

I want only those collections which satisfy all elements of datesArray.

I am using it in aggregation **$match** operator like:

```
Model.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
   'datesArray.start_date': { $gte: new Date('11-01-21') },
   'datesArray.end_date': { $lte: new Date('11-30-21') }
  }
}
])
```

I tried with **$elemMatch** but it matches at least one array element.
I also tried **$all** with **$elemMatch** but had no success.

Thank you

Comment: try like this
    {"$gte" : ISODate("2021-01-11T00:00:00Z"),}

Answer (score 1):

`$map` your `datesArray` to a boolean array by your date range matching criteria. Perform `$allElementsTrue` on the result to get your desired result.

`inputDate1` and `inputDate2` are your inputs. Feel free to update them.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "inputDate1": ISODate("2021-01-01"),
      "inputDate2": ISODate("2021-12-31")
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$allElementsTrue": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$datesArray",
              "as": "d",
              "in": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $gte: [
                      "$$d.start_date",
                      "$inputDate1"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      "$$d.end_date",
                      "$inputDate2"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Odb-ovZTyyt) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply invert each of the critera and use `$nor`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $nor: [
        {"datesArray.start_date": {$lt: ISODate("2021-11-01")}},
        {"datesArray.end_date": {$gt: ISODate("2021-11-30")}}
      ]
  }}
])
```